# Eliminates Duplicates

Tags: duplicates, oracle-sqldeveloper, cognos-11

I am using this expression definition in IBM Cognos Report studio 11, and they gives me duplicates values.
I want to modify to eliminates the duplicates (I have an unique field call Account Number).

This is the expression definition:

```
CASE WHEN ( [GL Application Master Monthly].[GL Application Master Monthly].[Current Interest Rate] > 0 and  [GL Application Master Monthly].[GL Application Master Monthly].[Current Interest Rate] <=3.75  and  [GL Application Master Monthly].[GL Application Master Monthly].[GL Account Number]  not in(1561162, 1590863, 1645463, 1698362, 1698664) )  THEN ([GL Application Master Monthly].[GL Application Master Monthly].[App Converted Yesterday Balance]) END
```

Comment: Duplicates of what?

What is the nature of the table?

When current interest rate changes, what happens?  Is a new record created? 

When you say you have a "unique field call (sic) Account Number" I'm assuming you are referring to GL Account Number. Do you mean that there is one and only one record in the table for each GL account number?

Comment: Have you tried Min or Max to remove the duplicates?

Comment: That would just be a band-aid and could obscure a problem.  It is necessary to understand what has happened and why before suggesting actions.  The most important is to establish the nature of the table in question. 

Also, using the between operator in the expression would be better.